# How to parse a DateTime string with like 03-22-2022 03:28 p.m. in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

As my question says i would like to parse a datetime with format like **03-22-2022 03:28 p.m. (month-day-year hour:minute a.m. or p.m.)** into t DateTime object in C#, not sure how to do this.

I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
var ss = "03-22-2022 03:28 p.m.";
format = "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm t.t.";

success = DateTime.TryParseExact(ss, format, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                    System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out DateTime result);
```

Comment: `t.t.` is not a valid pattern, and `p.m.` can't be parsed with any in-built default pattern. Simply replacing it first with `PM` and then parsing with `tt` would do, though.

Comment: Ok, so I need to do some parsing on the string with some custom code first in order for this to work then?

Comment: You don't need to parse anything, per se, a blind `.Replace("p.m.", "PM").Replace("a.m.", "AM")` should do it (since these strings are not likely to occur in any other capacity). Of course it's always a good idea to have a complete list of formats you are going to encounter, if at all possible.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thats actually what I meant by parse in this case. Thanks for confirming, can you post this as an actual answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: So I have found that this issue arrises due to different CultureInfo, hence adding `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` when converting date to string and vice versa fixes this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I recommend you not use a var, but a string instead for ss. It's also hard to tell where the "success" variable came from. You don't normally assign a value on the left-hand side if you are using an out variable in the right-hand side, unless you are trying to capture the boolean to determine if it worked. There is a way to do that without the success variable.

If I were to do it your way, where I use the var instead of string, and I use TryParse with an out variable, here's what I would do.

```
var ss = "03-22-2022 03:28 p.m.";
DateTime.TryParse(ss, out DateTime result);

return (result != DateTime.MinValue);
```

By using the DateTime in the out parameter, you are defining the variable inline. That allows you to use result later. Also, a DateTime variable is never null, so you can check to see if it is equal to DateTime.MinValue instead of creating another variable you are going to use in a conditional statement. Checking DateTime.MinValue will produce the same result. In my example, I am returning the result as if it were a function with a return value. You could use that any way you wanted.

If you are not returning a boolean value, but are using it later, you might do:

```
string ss = "03-22-2022 03:28 p.m.";
DateTime.TryParse(ss, out DateTime result)

if (result != DateTime.MinValue)
{
     //ToDo: continue process here
}
```

Others may have better advice, but this works for me.

Comment: And, the TryParse does parse the p.m. just fine.

Comment: It may well parse things "just fine" on your machine -- it does not on mine. That's the problem with implicitly relying on culture settings, and why it is a good idea to explicitly specify formats. If only to prevent ambiguity about whether "01-06-2022" is supposed to be interpreted as June 1, or January 6. Furthermore, using the `bool` return is *also* a good idea, because `0001-01-01`, while *unusual*, is nevertheless a *valid* value that a user might explicitly specify.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the whole point of `TryParse` is so that you can check the bool that is returned for success. I only put a snipped from my code, I do use the success variable later on in my actual codebase.